# React Router Link in image extends beyond image?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The Link for my image extends beyond the image itself:

[image]

There is a blank space between the edge of the image and the next element, which is a `Tabs` from Material UI I called `TradingTabs`.

This is what my code looks like:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
...
    <div className="header">
      <div className="header-left">
        <Link to="/">
              <img
                className="header-logo"
                src={logo}
                alt=""
              />
        </Link>
        <TradingTabs />
      </div>

      <div className="header-middle">
...
```

```
.header{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  }
  
  
  .header-left{
    margin-left: 2%;
    display: flex;
    width: 500px;
    align-items: center;
  }

.header-logo{
    width: 30%;
  }
```

How can I fix it so the Link only wraps the actual size of the image?

Comment: if you set the css width for header-logo to 100% does it fill in all that space?

Comment: Yes, then it seems to fill the space; however, I want it to be smaller.

Comment: what happens if you  add `className="header-logo"` to the link instead of the img?

Comment: The image shrinks as well, but it seems the white space shrinks too. However, the image still does not fill the white space.